# Magento - Get session GrandTotal?

Tags: php, magento

Right now i am using Mangeto 1.9.1 and i am trying to get the GrandTotal value of the session order in external php file in the main Magento directory.

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    $app = Mage::app('default'); 
    Mage::app();


    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quoteData= $quote->getData();
    $grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];


    echo "Grand: - $grandTotal";
?>
```

But it's not printing the value of the grand total.
Where is my mistake how i can make this thing work ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Just copy it and run it**

```
$grand=Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Get less, because magento only when the user logs on, the only initialization shopping cart 
 information, you can simulate login reacquisition.you can use this code:
 $customer_id='8261';
 echo Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id)->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Okey but how actually i can get the id of the logged user ?

Comment: Yes, you can get through the customer id, get the orders converted into    a shopping cart data

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste below code in the file that you wish to be.

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();//total items in cart

$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object

$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue()); //Subtotal value

$grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); //Grandtotal value
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ok for me.

```
$grand=Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
```